# CLI mounting vs. GUI mounting

Tags: command-line, mount, hard-drive, gui, automount

On Ubuntu 12.10, when I want to mount a hard drive, I can just click on the unmounted drive and everything works fine (by mounting to `/media/username/partitionlabel`).

Basically, I would like to do *exactly that* via command line (for a script I'm working on).

Since I **do not** want to automount on boot, fstab is out of the question (right?).

When I use mount on CLI, I need to specify a mountpoint (which needs to have a previously created mountpoint; also, I need to take care of permissions and whatnot) -- what I don't understand is where does the GUI take all its infos from? The mountpoint seems to depend on the partition's label, but such a directory doesn't exist before mounting. Also, the GUI way doesn't seem to care too much about a user not being root.

Is there an "easy" way to mount via CLI, just like it does on the GUI by clicking on an unmounted drive?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Nautilus and other file managers that mount drives (i.e., *the GUI*) use the `udisks` command.

This provides a *dynamic* mount, where the mount point is created for the drive on-the-fly, and when the drive is unmounted, the mount point goes away.

See [`man 1 udisks`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/udisks.1.html) for details on how to use this command (either manually, or called from a script/application). To learn more about how `udisks` works, see [`man 7 udisks`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man7/udisks.7.html).

To mount a device with `udisks`, you must specify a valid *device name* for the device. Specifying the device's *volume name* will not work. So, you can use `udisks` like this:

```
udisks --mount /dev/sdb1
```

When manually using `udisks` from the command-line, you might be best off to simply plug in a device, then run `dmesg | tail` shortly thereafter (see [`man dmesg`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/dmesg.1.html) and [`man tail`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/tail.1.html)) to discover the device name of the newly attached device.

This may not be the best way to write a script that mounts devices with `udisks`, however. I don't know exactly how you should do it, and it would be difficult to know since you haven't told us precisely *what* you want this script to do and *when* you want it to mount devices.

Comment: Thanks a lot -- `udisks` is exactly what I was looking for!

For whatever reason, I'm getting "Mount failed: Not Aouthorized" when running it via `ssh`; if I'm not pushing my luck, pointers would be appreciated as to how to fix it. ^^

Comment: @NicolaApicella How are you running it? You'll get a *not authorized* message if you try to run it from a remote session (including SSH) or from a crontab; by default non-root users can only mount volumes with `udisks` from local interactive logins. (They can still run a script from a local interactive login that uses `udisks`, though.)

Comment: Yes, sorry, just noticed (and edited) my previous comment: I'm indeed running it from `ssh`. (And currently googling a fix.)

Answer (score 7):

> Since I do not want to automount on boot, fstab is out of the question (right?).

Nope.  `noauto` keyword makes it skip mounting at boot time.

> Is there an "easy" way to mount via CLI, just like it does on the GUI by clicking on an unmounted drive?

Easiest would be to add it to `/etc/fstab` with `noauto` and use ...

```
mount /dir
```

This will have mount probe for a mountpoint and if not found then for a device in `/etc/fstab`.
`/dir` needs to exist though.

If either device or UUID are provided `/etc/fstab` is not probed. Like so ...

```
mount /dev/sda1 /media/directory
```

Or use [`udisks`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/udisks.1.html)  (I will let Eliah handle that >:-) )

---

mount generally is super user only.

Example options:

- `rw,noauto,user` mounts it as read+write but not at boot and you can do it as a  user.
- You can also add in permissions for a user in `/etc/fstab` for files. You can use `umask` for that.
- umask=0444 : everyone read, no write, no execute.
- umask=0333 : everyone read, execute.
- umask=0338 : owner, group read and execute; others, nothing

Comment: OK, I'll probably go ahead and try that, since it seems to be the "way to do it" anyway. :-)
So I guess I'll have to create a mountpoint-directory (with correct rights) anyway. ;-)

Comment: @Rinzwind Will a non-root user be able to mount the device?

Comment: @EliahKagan Yes, if you set the appropriate options in fstab (uid, user, ...).

Comment: @NicolaApicella I'm hoping this answer might be expanded to include information about that. :)

Comment: @NicApicella he likes to boss me around :=)

Answer (score 3):

In one of the comments, you said:

> For whatever reason, I'm getting "Mount failed: Not Aouthorized" when running it via ssh

I use [`pmount`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man1/pmount.1.html) instead of `udisks`.  It works over ssh.

If I remember correctly, this is the syntax/etc I use with it - most of mine are hidden behind aliases at this point:

```
pmount /dev/sdb1 my_usb
ls /media/my_usb/
eject /media/my_usb
```

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
udisks --mount /dev/sdb1
```

(replace `/dev/sdb1` with the device you want to mount)

Answer (score 1):

### udisksctl

An update, FYI.

The command suggested in [previous comment](https://askubuntu.com/a/270778/1544154) is not udisks anymore but udisksctl in recent linux distributions.

```
udisksctl mount -b /dev/sdc1
```

#### refereces

- https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/udisksctl.1.html
- https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Udisks