# When using /etc/fstab how can I use the username in the folder path

Tags: mount, 22.04, fstab

Other drives are mounted in the /media/user folder. I would like to mount my windows share folder in my /media/user folder as well for consistency. I've tried $USER and $username, but both options only create folders call '$USER' and '$username' in the /media folder.

Is there a way that I can mount my share in the correct folder?

Comment: The problem is that it is mounting the drives before any user logs in, so there is no way it would know the username.  You could however, setup some sort of script that you could run after logging in.

Comment: Or use systemd userspace service, see `man 5 systemd-system.conf`

Comment: or use a script - launched in `Startup Applications` - with `udisksctl mount --block-device /dev/$device;` in it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Do "personal fstab" files exist for user accounts?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/364954/do-personal-fstab-files-exist-for-user-accounts)